# Opening a file returns ErrorKind::Other 'Error: Os, code: 20, message: "Not a directory"'

Tags: file-io, rust

I'm trying to open a file, and if it doesn't exist create it. But for some reason I'm getting an error of `ErrorKind::Other` with the message `"Not a directory"`. Here is the full error I'm getting:

> thread 'main' panicked at 'Unknown error when opening file: Os { code: 20, kind: Other, message: "Not a directory" }', src/main.rs:53:17

Here is my code:

```rust
let mut filepath = std::env::current_exe()?;
filepath.push("days");
filepath.set_extension("toml");

let mut file = match File::open(filepath.clone()) {
    Ok(f) => f,
    Err(e) => match e.kind() {
        ErrorKind::NotFound => {
            {
                let mut create_file = File::create(filepath.clone());
                create_file.write_all(...); // Dummy data
            }
            File::open(filepath.clone())?
        },
        _ => {
            panic!("Unknow error when opening file: {:?}", e); // This is line 53
        }
    }
};
```

When I print the filepath to the console to check it I get `"/mnt/c/Projects/Other/random/hmdict/target/debug/hmdict/days.toml"`, which is correct.

Does anyone know why I'm getting os error 20 "Not a directory"?

P.S I'm using Rust `nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` with rustc version `1.46.0-nightly` in WSL running on Windows 10 build 18363 Version 1909

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is [push](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.push) creates a seperate path. If your executable location was `<what_ever>/hmdict`, your code creates a path `<whatever>/hmdict/days.toml`. Obviously, this path doesn't exist because `hmdict` is a executable file and not a directory.